# Yes/ No Is $X$ is homeomorphics to $Y$?

Tags: general-topology

$X=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x^2+y^2=1 \}$ and $Y=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x^2+y^2=1 \} \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: (x-2)^2+y^2=1 \} $  be the  subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Now my question is that

Is $X$ is homeomorphics to $Y$ ?

My attempt : Yes

Both $X$and $Y$ are connected and compact

Now by using the theorem connected subspaces of connected sets is connected

So $X$ is homeomorphics to $Y$

Is its true ?

Comment: The issue in your argument is that you assumed there is only one space (up to homeomorphism) which is both connected and compact. There's no reason to think this should be true!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The set $X$ is a circle. It is connected and it remains connected if you remove any point from it.

But $Y$ is the union of two circles, with a common point, which is $(1,0)$. If you remove that point from $Y$, what you get is disconnected.

So, $X$ and $Y$ are *not* homeomorphic.